# Build a pyramid with numbers between 1 and the inserted integer

Tags: c++

i'm trying to build a pyramid with numbers between 1 and the inserted number. For example, if i insert 6 to the integer, that the piramid will be as there:

```
12345654321
 234565432
  3456543
   45654
    565
     6
```

I tried using a for loop but i get in any line one or ++ numbers to 6.
This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j,d;
  std::cin >> d;
  for(i=1;i<=d;i++)
  {
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
       printf("%d",j);
     printf("\n");
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

How can i solve this problem building a pyramid like the shown.

Answer (score 10):

Since this is homework, I won't paste an algorithm, but here's a few hints:

- This `12345654321` can be printed by counting from one to six and then back to one.
- This `__3456543__` means that for numbers smaller than n, you have to output a `_` instead, where n depends on the level you are printing.
- Define your loop variables within the loop: `for(int i=1;i<=d;i++) ...` They are only interesting within the loop, and access outside the loop is usually an error, which is then flagged by the compiler.
- There's no need to for the `getch();` at the end. When you're in the debugger, you can put a breakpoint on the last line. If you aren't you don't want to have to press a key just to end your program.
- If you use `std::cout << j` and `std::cout << '\n'` for outputting, you don't need `printf()` either. (Once you want formatting, many will tell you that `printf` format strings are easier. I don't believe that, but would accept it, if it weren't that you can crash any application with an ill-formed `printf` format string, while it's much harder to come up with a way to crash your app using streams.)

Comment: The first bullet is actually incorrect. The first line can be printed by counting from one to six and then from five to one. You don't want to repeat the six.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe: "counting from one to six and then from six back to one" seems implied that you don't have to repeat the six again?

Comment: If "count from one to six" means 123456 then "from X to Y" means that both X and Y are included in the range. Hence "from six to one" would be 654321. I guess I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: and if you ditch getch() and printf() you don't need to include conio.h or stdio.h

Comment: @Frerich: I agree that this was misleading. I changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
for(j=i;j<=d;j++)
```

Also you forgot about formatting and the right side of the pyramid, but I think that's out of scope for this question and you can figure the code yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isn't exactly enough. I get the following:                                                              12345
2345
345
45
5

Comment: Well, I've only fixed an error in your code. I thought you could not find an error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: you have `D` rows, `1..D`. Six rows means your rows are numbered 1 to 6. Now, for each row `d`:

1. print `d-1` space characters. First row has no spaces, second has one and so on.
2. print the numbers `d..D`. So on the first line you print 1..6, on the second you print 2..6.
3. print the numbers `D-1..d`. So on the first line you print 5..1, on the second you print 5..2
4. print a new line

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to have the first line working the way you want.
2. Repeat it d times, where d is the number entered by the user.
3. Notice that on line l, numbers < l are replaced by spaces.